# How to set SW without throwing exceotion

Tags: javacard

I'm using javaCard 2.2.1 and trying to write some code to implement a part of global Platform
in my implementation i need to send an apdu with it's data and SW set to spatial value
how can i set the SW without using `IsoException.throwIt()`

Comment: Don't know if you can, you can probably send data and *then* throw an exception though.

Comment: Could you indicate if the given workaround is an option for you (and if not, why not?).

Comment: it is necessary because we need the key that is used in secure Chanel and additional implementation for example the APDU that contain just SW must have a mac

Comment: How about using the command setStatusWord from javacard.framework.service.basic service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly people use following way,

```
apdu.setOutgoingAndSend(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, length);
ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.XXX...);
```

Note that in second statement of the code, some JCVM/JCRE does not allow to throw arbitrary value of SW1SW2. They allow standard SW1s like `6Fxx`, `90xx`. You can code SW2 any value keeping SW1 standard.

Comment: the problem is that in this case we should indicate Le